HttpClient reusing causes issue with different lifetime in .net
I ran into a problem and haven't found an answer yet.
In short, we made a typed HttpClient and injected it into the singleton service. Everything seemed to be working fine.
Now we call this service inside BackgroundService and there are 10 calls in parallel there _testService.GetData(); - the first 10 work fine, the next requests are already stuck and time out. Something with the life cycle doesn't seem right.
It is when the client is reused a second time that the problem arises. The client seems to be transient, but the service will be singleton for now
services.AddHttpClient<ITestClient, TestClient>(client =>
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    
     // base address
});

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly ITestClient _client;
    private readonly ISettings _settings;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public NrdClient(
        ITestClient client,
        ISettings settings,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(client);
        _client = client;

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(settings);
        _settings = settings;

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(logger);
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Dto> GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await _client.PostAsync<T>(url, content);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClient : ITestClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public TestClient()
    {
    }

    public TestClient(HttpClient httpClient, ISettings settings)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(httpClient);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(settings);

        _client = httpClient;
        _client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
    }
    
    public async virtual Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string requestUrl, HttpContent content)
    {
        var response = await _client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content);

        using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        using GZipStream decompressed = new(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        using StreamReader reader = new(decompressed);
        using JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new(reader);

        return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
    }
}


The point of IServiceCollection.AddHttpClient is "Adds the IHttpClientFactory and related services to the IServiceCollection and configures a named HttpClient.", instead of injecting the http client into your TestClient, you should be injecting the IHttpClientFactory and using it's Create method to instantiate instances of your http client. There are dangers in creating your own HttpClient such as port exhaustion and DNS changes, and the IHttpClientFactory is the answer to some of these issues.

Here's a good document on why you should utilize the IHttpClientFactory: MSDN

the first 10 work fine, the next requests are already stuck and time out. What web server are you hitting? Are you sure the server you are hitting isn't limiting you to 10 incoming connections? e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/request-restrictions

yes. ain't no limit on the server side. some issues with the typed http client

If your client is injected as transient to a singleton class instance it effectively becomes a singleton itself, which can lead to some issues as well, this is nicely described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#dns-behavior
I think this is what you should be using according to Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#pooled-connections
Good practise is to also set BaseAddress for your Httpclient, that probably applies for your use case as well.
